# How to check if there is no data in firebase's real-time database?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
fun initFirebase(){
    var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    var table = database.getReference("ToiletDB")
    if(/*there is no data in database*/){
        for(i in 0 until toilets.length()) {
            val toilet = toilets.getJSONObject(i)
            var temp = table.push()
            temp.child("name").setValue(toilet.getString("FNAME"))
            temp.child("time").setValue(null)
            temp.child("facility").setValue(null)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write the data in the database only once for the first time. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

To check if data exists at the location, you'll need to attach a listener like this:

```
table.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```